# Convert string duration column to seconds

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

In the dataframe, one of the columns is duration. It was given as a string.

```
index         duration
1     1 hour, 2 minutes, 21 seconds
2     1 hour, 2 minutes, 26 seconds
3     1 hour, 2 minutes, 41 seconds
4     1 hour, 4 minutes, 39 seconds
5                1 hour, 42 seconds
6              6 minutes, 7 seconds
7              9 minutes, 7 seconds
8              9 minutes, 9 seconds
9              9 minutes, 9 seconds
10             9 minutes, 9 seconds
```

How can I convert this column into seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html?highlight=timedelta#pandas.Timedelta) to parse each item:

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(pd.Timedelta).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   duration
0      3741
1      3746
2      3761
3      3879
4      3642
5       367
6       547
7       549
8       549
9       549
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_str_to_seconds(string) -> int:
    l = string.split(', ') 
    total_seconds = 0
    for i in l:
        num_value = int(i.split(' ')[0])
        if 'hour' in i:
            total_seconds += num_value * 3600
        elif 'minute' in i:
            total_seconds += num_value * 60
        elif 'second' in i:
            total_seconds += num_value
    return total_seconds

df = pd.DataFrame()
l = ['1 hour, 2 minutes, 21 seconds', 
     '1 hour, 2 minutes, 26 seconds',
     '1 hour, 2 minutes, 41 seconds',
     '9 minutes, 7 seconds',
     '31 seconds']


df['duration'] = l
print(df)
df['duration'] = [convert_str_to_seconds(cell) for cell in df['duration']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                        duration
0  1 hour, 2 minutes, 21 seconds
1  1 hour, 2 minutes, 26 seconds
2  1 hour, 2 minutes, 41 seconds
3           9 minutes, 7 seconds
4                     31 seconds
   duration
0      3741
1      3746
2      3761
3       547
4        31
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. How would your suggestion work for the dataframe in question?

Comment: @JeruLuke, sorry, I didn't realize that the hours, minutes and seconds were all in the same column in the example DataFrame. I've updated my answer. There may be a built-in way to do this in Pandas, but if so I am unaware. I just wrote my own function.